# How to remove Authentication-related routes from ServiceStack Metadata Plugins?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there a way to remove authentication related routes (/auth, /assignroles, /authenticate) from ServiceStack metadata plugins (e.g. swagger and postman)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically add attributes for built-in Services by using the `AddAttributes()` extension methods. But as Services are pre-registered before `AppHost.Configure()` is called, you'll need to register them before, like in your AppHost Constructor:

```
public AppHost()
    : base("My Services", typeof(MyServices).Assembly)
{
    typeof(Authenticate)
        .AddAttributes(new ExcludeMetadataAttribute());
}
```

This has the same effect of adding them to the Request DTO or Service classes, e.g:

```
[ExcludeMetadata]
public class Authenticate { ... }
```

Which should exclude the built-in `Authenticate` Services from being displayed in ServiceStack's metadata services.